# In Python (without Pickle), Can Arbitrary JSON strings be Constructed Dynamically?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, pickle

In Python (2.7), is there a way to dynamically generate arbitrary JSON strings without using Pickle?

(To be clear, this inquiry dwells on constructing the JSON payload...long before invoking json.dumps().)

WHY?

Imagine you are undertaking a project that will involve interacting with several complex APIs (using JSON).

Each instance of EVERY JSON object that will be built and POSTed to the API(s) could well require a unique hierarchical structure (many, many levels of objects...a blizzard of ':', ',', '[]', '{}' ... you get the idea).

Other than instantiating a Python object and serializing it via Pickle, Is there an easier way to construct complex, arbitrary JSON strings that doesn't rely on hand/hard-coding a structure in place; such as this [poor] example:

```
json_string = '{' + '"field_a": [ {' + '"id":' + id + '", "category":' + category . . . + '] }'
```

Your thoughts? Suggestions? Comments?

Comment: This question seems to be about working with JSON -- Why are you talking about `pickle`?  That's a completely _different_ serialization technique.

Comment: Why not instantiate Python objects and serialize with `json.dumps()`? This seems eminently doable with list/dict comprehensions.  It also has the added benefit of guaranteeing correctly formatted json.  Constructing json by hand seems fraught with peril.

Answer (score 1):

**Default JSON encoder** is capable of creating a JSON from some basic types (e.g. int, str, list, dict), but it can't handle custom objects.

For example:

```
json.dumps([1, 2, 3])  # this works: '[1, 2, 3]'

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value1 = 1
        self.value2 = {'foo': ['bar', 'baz']}

json.dumps(A())  # this fails
```

### Custom JSON Encoders

Luckily, json allows creating custom JSON encoders.

A custom JSON encoder does not have to create JSON. It just hs to convert an object into something that can be converted to JSON!

So, it is enough to create a dictionary.

The simplest solution is to use the `__dict__` - that will work for most custom classes, because `__dict__` contains a dictionary of all member variables, and dictionaries can be encoded into JSON by the built-in encoder:

```
class DictJsonEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        return obj.__dict__

json.dumps(a, cls=DictJsonEncoder)  # '{"value2": {"foo": ["bar", "baz"]}, "value1": 1}'
```

### A More Flexible Solution

For more flexibility, don't always use `__dict__` (but use it as the default).

A common pattern is to implement `__json__` method which does what is needed and use that when available:

```
class MyJsonEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if hasattr(obj, '__json__'):
            return obj.__json__()
        else:
            return super(MyJsonEncoder, self).default(obj)
```

Then implement the default `__json__` method which returns `__dict__`:

```
class JsonCapable(object):
    def __json__(self):
        return self.__dict__

class A(JsonCapable):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value1 = 1
        self.value2 = {'foo': ['bar', 'baz']}

    # For special needs, override __json__ here

json.dumps(a, cls=MyJsonEncoder)  # '{"value2": {"foo": ["bar", "baz"]}, "value1": 1}'
```

---

Alternatively, the encoder could use `__json__` if it finds it and `__dict__` as backup. Then there is no need for a `JsonCapable` class.